# Executing command as awk function

Tags: bash, awk

I need a report in which we will be calculating the values from the below output of these 2 command. Below sample is the actual requirement.

**First command output**

```
$ isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail"
Size:573T
Used:448.0T
Avail:74T
```

**Second command output**

```
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "\t\t\tSnapshot USED %=%.1f%%\n", $4}'
     Snapshot USED =0.6%
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n -1 | awk '{ print "\t\t\tSnapshot USED:" $1}'
     Snapshot USED=3.2T
```

With this below comand I am getting the first 4 command as an output but how do we execute the snapshot command in awk.
I tried the call system  funstion in awk but not working.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=":";h["Iie"]="Total Size";h["Eed"]="Total Used";h["vail"]="Avilable"}$1 in h{sub(/T/," TB",$2);print h[$1],$2; h[$1]=$2 }END{print "Used (%)",h["Eed"]/h["Iie"]*100}' infile
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n -1 | awk '{ print "Snapshot USED=" $1}'
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "Snapshot USED %:%.1f\n", $4}'
```

**Sample Requirement**

```
Total Size      : 573 TB
Total Used      : 448.0 TB
Total Available : 74 TB
Total Used %    : 86.1 %   # Total Used(%) = Total Used/Total Size *100 = 86.1(%)
Snapshot Used   : 3.2 TB
Snapshot Used % : 0.6 %
Used w/o        : 85.5 %    # {(Total used)-(Snapshot used)} / (Total size) = 85.49%
```

**Two way communication example**

The first command output is not displayed

```
isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail" | awk '{print "\t\t\t"$1 $2}' |& isi_classic snapshot usage | awk -v OFS='\t\t\t' 'END{printf "%sSnapshot USED %:%.1f%%\n%sSnapshot USED:%s\n",OFS,$4,OFS,$1}'
                        Snapshot USED :0.6%
                        Snapshot USED:3.3T
```

Comment: What does it mean merging the snapshot command to awk?

Comment: @robert Sorry, but we don't mean that, executing another command in awk and get them as variable for another calculation. which is `used w/o`.